# JQuery unpack array of parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm using typeahead [typeahead](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/)
as following:

`$('my_elements').typeahead(options, dataset1, dataset2, ...)`. However number of datasets is dynamic, and I have them calculated and stored in an array(along with options). So how to pass the array as the arguments list? I tried using javascript apply function:

```
 $('my_elements').each(function(){
   typeahead.apply(this, params_array);
 });
```

But an error is genereated: typeahead is not defined! So how to use apply function on the result of jquery selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to access `typeahead` directly, it tries to find a reference with that name in the current scope or in a ancestor scope.

But since `typeahead` is a plugin it is a property of the jQuery prototype object, so you need to access it via `$.fn.typeahead`.

Another pointed to be noted is `this` inside the plugin should refer to jQuery object not dom element so

```
$('my_elements').each(function () {
    $.fn.typeahead.apply($(this), params_array);
});
```

or

```
$.fn.typeahead.apply($('my_elements'), params_array);
```